# Not only not A, but also B. Does this imply B or not B?

Tags: conjunctions, negation

Let's take the following two statements.

> He who lives in a glass house shall not cast stones (1)
>
> He who lives in a glass house shall have his toilet in the basement. (2)

Now, if we try to combine them like this:

> Not only shall he who lives in a glass house not cast stones, but also have his toilet in the basement. (3)

Does this mean he shall have his toilet in the basement or that they shall *not* have his toilet in the basement? How far does the scope of the *not* in *shall not cast stones* go?

This is the actual example I was thinking about. It is possible to construct a more concise one:

> Not only was it not green, but also red.

Was *it* red or wasn't it?

If it so happens that this is an inherently ambiguous and/or ungrammatical sentence/structure, then I am ready to accept that as an answer as well.

Comment: Yes and yes...toilet in basement and red.  Strip out the details and you have "not only but also".

Comment: I wouldn't use whole clauses in this construction. It works with normal noun phrases to create a new noun phrase, like "not only mustard, but also ketchup." If you have to connect clauses, I would do it this way: "**Not only** was it not green, it was red." (so, repeat the subject and the verb)  But having two instances of the word "not" so close together doesn't look good to me.

Comment: But I’d write: *Not only shall he who lives in a glass house not cast stones, but he shall also have his toilet in the basement*

Comment: _But_ means _and_, logically. _`A` but `B`_ just means _`A` and `B`_, with an additional invited inference that `B` is somehow surprising to the speaker, or that the speaker expects the addressee to find `B` surprising. Or both, which is the prototype.

Comment: I am afraid most people misread the question. @KristinaLopez The question is really whether we have "not only not X but also [not] Y".

Comment: Anyway, the title is quaintly ambiguous, too. My first reading was "Does this imply (B or not B)?" Yes, it does.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes, but my concern is the second not in the "not only" clause which might potentially carry influence over to the "but also" clause.

Comment: @anemone: anything at all implies (B or not B) doesn't it?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Indeed. That was my problem.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան - The sentence you asked about -- **Not only shall he not cast stones, but also have his toilet in the basement* -- is ungrammatical. It should be _.., but he shall also ..._  Conjunction Reduction won't delete _he shall_ under identity with _shall he_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you interpret the construction

> Not only was it not X, but also Y.

depends on where you locate the node that the parallel elements in the construction attach to—and consequently what the parallel elements themselves are. It is possible for people to disagree on this issue, which means that some level of ambiguity is inherent in the construction. Nevertheless, I think that the most logical way to read the wording is to see it as establishing the connection point immediately after "was it"/"it was." This makes the parallel branches "not X" and "Y," and it means that, with the implied words "it was" in place, we get this result:

> Not only was it **not X**, but also [it was] **Y**.

The alternative reading is to infer that the parallelism arises immediately after the word *not*, yielding the parallel branches "X" and "Y." But this interpretation requires two interpolations in the original sentence:

> Not only was it not **X**, but [it was] also [not] **Y**.

which I think requires a reader or hearer to perform a more complicated set of mental gymnastics in order to reach the desired result, making it (to me) a less plausible interpretation.

If I were a lawyer trying to persuade a court that a contract specifying "Not only not X but Y" meant "neither X nor Y," I would certainly argue for the more complicated reading, but if I were the judge, I wouldn't buy it.

Comment: @anemone: Thanks for pointing out the serious mistake I made in overlooking the presence of _not_ at a crucial point in the OP's example. I have reworked my earlier answer to take that crucial word's presence into account, and I hope that the answer now has some practical value.

Comment: Very well put, I think.